# How to call flow from @controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

When I navigate /app/wb/create, I will go into the below controller method which needs to call the flow "/app/main" but spring resove it to "/main.xhtml" . My question is how to redirect to flow from spring controller?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/wb")
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */

        @RequestMapping("/create/")
        public String home(Device device, Model model) {
            if (device == null) {
                logger.info("no device detected");
            } else if (device.isNormal()) {
                logger.info("Device is normal");
            } else if (device.isMobile()) {
                logger.info("Device is mobile");
            } else if (device.isTablet()) {
                logger.info("Device is tablet");
            }
            return "app/main"; // Where main is the flow id
        }
}
```

**Flow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="user" class="com.veera.myapp.domain.UserEntity" />
    <view-state id="welcome" view="welcome.xhtml">
        <transition on="newUser" to="signUp" />
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="signUp" view="signUp.xhtml" model="user">
        <transition on="backToSignIn" to="welcome" />
    </view-state>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return "/main";
```

you have to remove your application path

Comment: Will that find the view from flow?

Comment: When I add "/main" it is looking for /main.xhtml not the view main from the webflow.

Comment: the flow will start with the first state defined in the flow.xml by default

Answer (score 0):

```
return "redirect:/main.xhtml"
```

You have to tell controller to redirect.

Comment: It need to redirect to the flow not xhtml page.

Comment: What is your webflow configuration?